# "A field or property with the name'EncrypedStatusId' was not found on the selected data source."

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, gridview

Hi ,
I have added a new value EncrypedStatusId in DataNavigateUrlFields
And i am getting error as 
"A field or property with the name'EncrypedStatusId' was not found on the selected data source."
but my list do has the property EncrypedStatusId which contain value 
How to solve this?
ASPX:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="Status" DataTextField="AppStatus" DataNavigateUrlFields="NavigateUrl,Id,EncrypedStatusId"
            SortExpression="AppStatus" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="{0}?Id={1}"></asp:HyperLinkField>
<asp:TemplateField>
     <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("NavigateUrl","{0}").Replace(":", Server.UrlEncode(":")) %>'
                    DataTextField="AppStatus"></asp:HyperLink>
     </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

CODE BEHIND :

```
List<DTO> listDto;
IApplication engine;

engine = new Engine();
listDto = engine.ReadHistory(Session["UserID"].ToString());

this.dvHistory.DataSource = listDto;
this.dvHistory.DataBind();
```

Comment: `DataNavigateUrlFormatString` has only two and you have specified 3, I am not sure whether its acceptable or not

Comment: Perhaps `EncrypedStatusId` is not accessible can you post the relevant code for the same ?

Comment: By the way: remove the DataTextField in HyperLink1 and add Text='<%# Eval("AppStatus") %>' instead

Answer (score 0):

do you have it in the gridview property datakeynames=[EncrypedStatusId,...]

Answer (score 0):

Check that the column `EncrypedStatusId` column exists in your datasource.